# jquery easytabs - how to include external link in tab

Tags: jquery

This is for jquery easytabs by http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/

I'm trying to include an external link in one of the tabs but its not working, works fine otherwise.

Here's my setup:

Head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#tab-container').easytabs();
});
</script>
```

Tabs:

```
<div id="tab-container" class="tab-container">
  <ul>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="/external-link.html">External Link</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#tab4">Tab 4</a></li>
  </ul>
```

I have searched around and found a few mentions about how to do this but none of them worked for me, so any suggestions are much appreciated.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you try ajax loads as your given link also suggests that in `Available Options` tab?

Comment: Thanks DKM, that was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow easytab to include page from external link you should add data-target attributes
so your code now will be ,

```
<div id="tab-container" class="tab-container">
<ul>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="/external-link.html" data-target="#tabs-ajax-js">External Link</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#tab4">Tab 4</a></li>
  </ul> 
<div>
```

i hope it work with you :)